# Sencha touch 2 : TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'item.element.detach') in ST2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am using **Sencha Touch 2**

I have a list of items, on tap it will be navigate to a view related to that item. On that view there is a **Back Button** and  a **Skip button** in navigation bar.
On back it will navigate to list menu.
On skip it will navigate to view related to next item in the list.

**Example-**  Lets say there are **five items(1,2,3,4,5)** in the list and if I **tap on Item 1** now it will navigate to the view related to item 1, on that view if I tap Skip button It will directly switch to  the view related to **Item 2** and if i tap back button, then i want it to navigate to list(or list menu) directly.(not to view related to item 1)
 and so on with Item 3,4,5 on further tap.

For this - I am doing **pop()** operation for current view and then **push(next view)**.

Step 1-  **this.getMyNav().pop(1);**  (POP Item 1)

Step 2-  **this.getMyNav().push(next view object);** (Push item 2)

Sometimes It is showing this error - **TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'item.element.detach') in sencha touch 2 in console**. But application is working even with that error in console.(**Safari Browser**)

Is there any fix to this? or is there any alternative to do this?

Comment: May be not related to the error, you can just use this.getMyNav().pop(); it just removes an item from top of the stack.

Comment: Still giving error even after using this.getMyNav().pop(); in place of this.getMyNav().pop(1);